# Stepper Motor with ULN2003 drivers only vibrates and does not turn

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, pins, motordriver

I've been trying to get the Stepper Motor to work for over a week now. It's not been responding to my python script for a while now.

When I just bought the Stepper Motor everything worked fine and I had zero problems. Now, a few weeks later, it does not seem to respond. The lights on the ULN2003-board are lighting up but the motor itself is not turning, just vibrating. This made me thinks that it was a wire or script problem, but it does not seem like it. I've tried some other scripts and changed the wires a couple of times, to no avail.

This is the code that used to work:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)


# 7=A, 11=B, 13=C, 15=D 
control_pins = [7,11,13,15] 

while 1:
  for pin in control_pins:
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin, 0)

  halfstep_seq = [
    [1,0,0,0], # Step 1
    [1,1,0,0], # Step 2
    [0,1,0,0], # Step 3
    [0,1,1,0], # Step 4
    [0,0,1,0], # Step 5
    [0,0,1,1], # Step 6
    [0,0,0,1], # Step 7
    [1,0,0,1]  # Step 8
  ]

  for i in range(512):
    for halfstep in range(8):
      for pin in range(4):
        GPIO.output(control_pins[pin], halfstep_seq[halfstep][pin])
      time.sleep(0.001)
```

And yes, I know GPIO.cleanup() should be in there. I deleted it on purpose so the loop would keep running. This way it was easier for me to detect any mistakes instead of the motor just making 1 circle and stopping everytime.

I honestly expect the motor to just be broken for some reason. Don't know how, don't know when, but it probably hit something that broke the motor on the inside.

If there's anyone with more experience who could tell me what to do in this situation, please help me.

Comment: You could try increasing the length of the sleep significantly (10 seconds), and check the high/low wires connected directly to the stepper are what you expect them to be at each stage of the rotation sequence.

Comment: Alright, so I have tried this and the thing that made this situation really weird is that the first 2 times I tested it, the program crashed for a second on the 4th step in the sequence. The 3th time I tested it (for your information, I did not adjust anything) it ran perfectly. Because I thought it was fixed magically, I tried turning the sleep down to the original amount. This again, did not work. Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: I would like to add something to my last comment. I have now tested the Motor with different wires connected to it and it always seems to crash on exactly the same letter, letter C (the letters A,B,C,D are connected to the GPIO pins on the RPI). So going from step 3 to 4 in the sequence makes something crash.

Answer (score 0):

So my guess would be that the step time you are using (the sleep time) is just too short, the motor doesnt have enough time to turn to the new position before you are trying to drive it to the next one. Effectively the program is getting ahead of what the motor is capable of. It may be that the physical bearings in the motor have degraded slightly, or the driving circuit isn't able to drive the motor as hard (lower voltage/power than when it worked). Does the motor's tech spec provide a maximum theoretical RPM that it could be driven at? Does it provide a minimum step-time or similar information that could guide this?

As an aside, if you say something crashed, it's really helpful to provide the stack trace or other error output so people can try to help understand why and what exactly isn't working.

Comment: I could not find anything about the motor's RPM other than the standard. The best site I could find to set up the motor and the script would be this one: https://medium.com/@Keithweaver_/controlling-stepper-motors-using-python-with-a-raspberry-pi-b3fbd482f886 About the crash report, the motor did not actually crash within the script. It crashed at the fourth step which really did not do anything to the script (so, no error output), but the lights just did not turn on after step four and eventually reset to step 1. Meanwhile the script keeps running without errors.